# I have Power of Attorney for a single relative - do they need a Last Will and Testament also?

Tags: wills, power-of-attorney, kentucky

I have a properly notarized Power of Attorney letter for a single relative in Kentucky.

Does that relative also need a Last Will and Testament, or does my PoA cover whatever may need to be done when they eventually pass away?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two relevant laws of Kentucky. KRS Chapter 457 is about power of attorney, and KRS [457.100](https://apps.legislature.ky.gov/law/statutes/statute.aspx?id=48270) specifies how the POA terminates, in particular (1)(a) says that it terminates when the principal dies (therefore on death of the relative, you have no power).

[KRS Chapter 391](https://apps.legislature.ky.gov/law/statutes/chapter.aspx?id=39189) governs [intestate](https://dictionary.law.com/Default.aspx?selected=1016) succession i.e. what happens if you don't have a will. The disposition of the estate depends on what living relatives there are.

If the person is unmarried, the estate goes to the children or descendants. If there are no children, it goes to the parents; otherwise to siblings.

If there are no living relatives whatsoever, then the estate goes to the state in [escheat](https://dictionary.law.com/Default.aspx?selected=655).

A will is therefore necessary if the person wants something other than intestate default. Also, inheritance via intestacy is procedurally inconvenient compared to a simple will saying who gets what.

Comment: FWIW, the term what the estate going to the state because a person has no sufficiently close living relatives is "escheat."

Answer (score 0):

### Death ends a power of attorney

To be clear, the death of either of you.

In general, so does your relative becoming legally incompetent (e.g. severe illness, dementia, vegetative state etc.) unless it is an *enduring* power of attorney.

So yes, they need a will.

Comment: How would my relative becoming legally incompetent affect the PoA they had me sign to manage their health, financial, etc decisions for them?

Comment: The agent's death terminated that agent's authority, going forward, but not necessarily the POA instrument, which may name a successor agent.

Comment: @warren because that’s the law

Comment: @DaleM - what's the point of a PoA to handle medical decisions if someone becomes unable to do so if "the law" says you can't? That's irrational

Comment: @warren because when the person loses the power to revoke the attorney, it’s automatically revoked. An enduring power is made specifically in contemplation of not being able to revoke.

Comment: @DaleM - whole point of a PoA is to be able to make legal decisions for someone else. What *you're* saying the law says is, "you know that document your friend signed so you could make decisions for them? Yeah. It's no good because they're in a coma." That's not how a PoA works in any state I've ever seen.

Comment: @warren "It's no good because they're in a coma." This is the common law rule. But durable powers of attorney that expressly provide that they survive incapacity are authorize by statute or case law in every U.S. states. Death always terminates a POA (or in some states by statute, knowledge of death by the agent rather than actual death).

Comment: The common terminology in the us is "durable" rather than "enduring".

Comment: @ohwilleke not in Australia